# Hidden element with transition sometimes not transitioning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following to get JSON after clicking a submit button, where `temperature` is the div wrapper for the other listed elements:

```
$.getJSON("lookup.php?id=" + v, function(data) {
    var items = {};
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items[key] = parseFloat(val.replace(/\$|,/g, '')).toFixed(2);
    });
    console.log(items);
    if (items["goal"] != null) {
        $('#progress').on('webkitTransitionEnd transitionend', function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        });
        $("#goal").text("Goal: " + "$" + items["goal"]);
        $("#temperature").css("display", "block");
        $("#progress").css("width", items["total"] / items["goal"] * 100 + "%");
        $("#pct").text(items["total"] / items["goal"] * 100 + "%");
        $("#raised").text("$" + items["total"]);
    }
});
```

This code is inside a jQuery `getJSON` function. And the temperature should animate like a fundraiser temperature bar.

Here's what I have for that element's CSS:

```
#progress {
  float: left;
  transition: width 6s;
  width: 0%;
  height: 20px;
  background: #FF5D50;
  z-index: 333;
}
```

I've been getting inconsistent results with the transitions (I am aware that I should be adding the other browser CSS transitions as well). I'm using Chrome. Sometimes it loads and the transition happens, and sometimes it just loads directly to the percent it's supposed to be at. It should be animating every time, and without making changes to the code, I get different results like it's a race condition, and so it's very difficult to reproduce consistently. However, I read from other answers here on SO that DOM manipulation is synchronous. So I can't understand why sometimes it works and doesn't.

I would appreciate any explanation to what's happening here. Maybe what's checking to see if there needs to be a transition applied is being triggered sometimes before the display attribute changes and this is why it will sometimes not transition? I don't know what exactly checks if a DOM element is changed and applies the CSS transition.

Update: It works even with a 0ms `setTimeout` that encapsulates the progress bar update after changing the wrapper to display as block - can't reproduce on fiddle since it looks like it runs slower there.

Comment: Could you post also your getJSON function, please? Have you put your jQuery code on `done` callback method? I tried to replicate a call delay but here it's work. So my question is: are you sure to have all your json data before call your progress function? https://jsfiddle.net/j9revdf6/3/

Comment: @ReSedano edited my post. I definitely have everything